# How to change the location of backups in Think Vantage Rescue and Recovery?

Tags: backup, thinkpad

With Think Vantage Rescue and Recovery, I could set an network location to save backup files. However, since I got a new NAS, R&R stopped working because it could not find the old file server anymore. As a result, I guess I have change the location where R&R could save backup files. It seems I simply have no way to do it. When I select "Network" as the backup location. R&R is trying to access the old file server again.

How could I change the default location for these backups?

Answer (score 0):

The way I remember it is that you can change the settings of this in the registry file, see  page 22 in [RR deployment manual](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/thinkvantage_en/rnr43dg.pdf).